# Simpler way of matrix operation using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, matrix

I have a code like this:

```
x = 0
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        x += f[i, 0] * f[0, j]
```

Here `f` is a 2D array. Now, is there a function available in numpy that can be used to do this without using for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make use of NumPy's `outer()`. This is basically an outer product problem where you simply sum the elements of the resulting outer product n*n matrix. Here, the only values which you are using in your matrix are the first row and the first column.

So, all you need to do is to take the outer product of the first row and the first column using `np.outer` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)). This is all what you are doing in your algorithm with nested for-loops.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np

f = np.random.randint(1, 9, (3, 3)) # Create a test 3x3 matrix 

col = f[:, 0] # first column enteries [5, 3, 8]
row = f[0, :] # first row enteries [5, 3, 4]
summ = np.sum(np.outer(row, col))

print (f)
print ('The sum is %d' %summ)

#[[5 3 4]
# [3 8 1]
# [8 7 2]]

# The sum is 192
```

**Alternative** as suggested by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) is

```
np.einsum('i,j->', f[:,0], f[0,:])
```

Comment: The same thing using `np.einsum`: `np.einsum('i,j->', f[:,0], f[0,:])`.  The outer part was easy.  I had to play around to figure out how to tell it to sum (the empty `->`).

Comment: It's worth noting that almost any nested sum like in the original question can be done in numpy using einsum.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum the first column and first row independently, then take the product:

```
res = f[:, 0].sum() * f[0, :].sum()
```

Here's some code to check this gives what you expect:

```
np.random.seed(0)

f = np.random.random((100, 100))

x = 0
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        x += f[i, 0] * f[0,j]

res = f[:, 0].sum() * f[0, :].sum()

assert np.isclose(x, res)
```